# limit or extend the number of samples that are played

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, sampling, trigonometry

I'm trying out the code in [this example](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html) and basically I want to limit the number of samples that are played.

Right now once you hit the play button the app plays a tone at the frequency that was set but it doesn't stop until you hit stop. I would like to only play a sound for a second long.

Any idea how to do that? I already tried changing inNumberFrames to 44100 but all that does is make my tone unstable.

```
// Generate the samples
for (UInt32 frame = 0; frame < inNumberFrames; frame++) 
{
    buffer[frame] = sin(theta) * amplitude;

    theta += theta_increment;
    if (theta > 2.0 * M_PI)
    {
        theta -= 2.0 * M_PI;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Kurt Revis says that CoreAudio calls your RenderTone() function repeatedly. I didn't think of this but I guess that makes sense. It does lead me to another question though: what happens if i want to send like a 4 minute song to the buffer? (44100 * 60 * 4 samples)

If the RenderTone method gets called repeatedly I'm guessing it will each time start playing the samples from the start. How can I play a long set of samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities.

1. High-level: When you start playing, make an NSTimer that calls a method to call `-stop` after one second. Or use `-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]`.
2. Low-level: In `RenderTone()`, keep track of how many samples have been played already. Across calls to `RenderTone()`, keep that value in an ivar in the view controller, exactly the same way as it does with `theta`.  In the sample-generation loop, if the sample count is >= 44100, set `buffer[frame]` to 0.

The fundamental thing to understand is: CoreAudio calls your `RenderTone()` function repeatedly, whenever it needs more audio data to play. It asks you for a certain amount of data (`inSampleCount`), and you need to provide exactly that much, no more, no less. If you want it to play silence, then you need to fill the buffer with zeros.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I updated my question, can you take a look?

Comment: You are the one supplying the samples. It's up to you to make it do what you want. If you want to play a long sound, then it is up to you to keep track of what samples you've already played and which ones are next. If you want an easier way to do it, you should look at [Audio Queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) which is a higher-level API.

Comment: For instance. Let's say you have 100 samples, and you want to play them from the beginning. Make a variable 'i', which is the index of the next sample to be played. Initially it's 0.  CoreAudio asks you for 5 samples to play, so you fill its buffer with samples 0-4 (i through i+4), and set i to 5. Then CoreAudio asks you for 5 more samples, and you fill its buffer with samples 5-9 (i through i+4), and set i to 10.  And so on.

Comment: I'll have a look at AQ too. Thanks for your help